# Selected Values in dynamic Dash Components are not storing in DB

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I have this DASH app where components are dynamically created in two different tabs on a single page. I am having hard storing selected values to the Database in a table. My code displays everything correctly but callback on button does not seem to work. I believe the issue is with how values are being selected and persisted in components. I am open to suggestions.

```
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly.express as px
from dash import dcc, html, dash_table, Input, Output, State
import dash_mantine_components as dmc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
import json
import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime as dt
from dash import callback
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
data = {'tab': ['Study Information', 'Questionnaire' ,'Study Information', 'Questionnaire', 'Questionnaire'],
        'question': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'answer_type': ['Dropdown', 'DateTime', 'DateTime', 'MultiSelect', 'MultiSelect'],
        'answers': ['1,2,3', '', '', 'p,q,r', 'xyz']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def get_studyinfo():
    # create a dataframe 
    data = df[df['tab'] == 'Study Information'] 
    return data

dynamiccomponentList = []
dfq = get_studyinfo()
for row in dfq.index:
    if dfq["answer_type"][row] == "Dropdown":
        print("yes")
        dynamiccomponentList.append(html.Br())
        b = dfq["answers"][row].split(",")
        c = dfq["question"][row]
        comp_text = dmc.MultiSelect(
            label=c,
            description="You can select applicable value.",
            data=b,
            maxSelectedValues=1,
            style={"width": 400},
        )
    elif dfq["answer_type"][row] == "MultiSelect":
        print("no")
        dynamiccomponentList.append(html.Br())
        b = dfq["answers"][row].split(",")
        c = dfq["question"][row]
        comp_text = dmc.MultiSelect(
            label=c,
            description="You can select all applicable values.",
            data=b,
            maxSelectedValues=3,
            style={"width": 400},
        )
    elif dfq["answer_type"][row] == "DateTime":
        print("no1")
        dynamiccomponentList.append(html.Br())
        b = dfq["answers"][row].split(",")
        c = dfq["question"][row]
        comp_text = dmc.DatePicker(
            id=f"date-picker-{row}",
            label=c,
            description="Select a date",
            minDate=dt(2020, 8, 5),
            # value=dt.now().date(),
            style={"width": 200},
        )
    elif dfq["answer_type"][row] == "Textbox":
        print("no1")
        dynamiccomponentList.append(html.Br())
        c1 = dfq["question"][row]
        input_component = dcc.Input(type="text")
        comp_text = html.Div(
            [
                html.Label(c1),
                html.Br(),
                input_component
            ]
        )

    dynamiccomponentList.append(comp_text)

def get_questionnaire():
    # create a dataframe 
    data = df[df['tab'] == 'Questionnaire'] 
    return data

dynamiccomponentList2 = []
pfq = get_questionnaire()
for row in pfq.index:
    if pfq["answer_type"][row] == "Dropdown":
        print(f"Dropdown-{row}")
        dynamiccomponentList2.append(html.Br())
        b = pfq["answers"][row].split(",")
        c = pfq["question"][row]
        comp_text = dmc.MultiSelect(
            label=c,
            id=f"Dropdown-{row}",
            description="You can select applicable value.",
            data=b,
            maxSelectedValues=1,
            style={"width": 400},
        )
    elif pfq["answer_type"][row] == "MultiSelect":
        print(f"MultiSelect-{row}")
        dynamiccomponentList2.append(html.Br())
        b = pfq["answers"][row].split(",")
        c = pfq["question"][row]
        comp_text = dmc.MultiSelect(
            label=c,
            id=f"MultiSelect-{row}",
            description="You can select all applicable values.",
            data=b,
            maxSelectedValues=3,
            style={"width": 400},
        )
    elif pfq["answer_type"][row] == "DateTime":
        print(f"datepicker-{row}")
        dynamiccomponentList2.append(html.Br())
        b = pfq["answers"][row].split(",")
        c = pfq["question"][row]
        comp_text = dmc.DatePicker(
            id=f"datepicker-{row}",
            label=c,
            description="Select a date",
            minDate=dt(2020, 8, 5),
            # value=dt.now().date(),
            style={"width": 200},
        )
    elif pfq["answer_type"][row] == "Textbox":
        print(f"inputbox-{row}")
        dynamiccomponentList2.append(html.Br())
        c = pfq["question"][row]
        input_component = dcc.Input(type="text", id=f"inputbox-{row}")
        comp_text = html.Div(
            [
                html.Label(c),
                html.Br(),
                input_component
            ]
        )

    dynamiccomponentList2.append(comp_text)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Tabs(
            id="tabs",
            value="1",  # Update the value to a string
            children=[
                dcc.Tab(
                    label="Study Information",
                    value="1",  # Update the value to a string
                    children=[
                        *dynamiccomponentList2,
                        html.Br(),
                    ],
                ),
                dcc.Tab(
                    label="Questionnaire",
                    value="2",  # Update the value to a string
                    children=[
                        *dynamiccomponentList,
                        html.Br(),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        ),
        html.Div(
            children=dash_table.DataTable(
                id="table-dropdown31",
                data=get_studyinfo().to_dict("records"),
            ),
            style={"display": "none"},
        ),
        html.Br(),html.Button(
            "Save",
            className="btn btn-lg btn-primary",
            id="submit-button225",
        )
        ,html.Br(),
        dcc.Link(
            html.Button(
                "Applicable System Output List",
                className="btn btn-lg btn-primary",
                #id="submit-button225",
            ),
            href="/page55",
            style={"textDecoration": "none"},
            refresh=True,
        ),
        html.Div(id="output1yy"),
        dcc.Interval(id="interval_6", interval=84600000 * 7, n_intervals=0),
        html.Div(id="hidden-div6611", style={"display": "none"}),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("hidden-div6611", "children"),
    Input("table-dropdown31", "data"),
)
def update_hidden_div(data):
    return json.dumps(data)

@app.callback(
    Output("output1yy", "children"),
    Input("submit-button225", "n_clicks"),
    State("tabs", "value"),
    *[State(f"inputbox-{row}", "value") if hasattr(row, "inputbox") else State(f"MultiSelect-{row}", "value") if hasattr(row, "MultiSelect") else State(f"datepicker-{row}", "date") if hasattr(row, "datepicker") else State(f"Dropdown-{row}", "value") for row in range(len(pfq))],
)
def store_answers(n_clicks, tab_value, *values):
    if n_clicks is None:
        return html.Div()

    # Connect to the database
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="testDB",
        user="postgres",
        password="1234",
        host="localhost",
        port="5433"
    )

    # Create a cursor object
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Insert the entered values into the "answers_submitted" table
    for row in range(len(pfq)):
        # Get the question ID from the index
        question_id = pfq["id"][row]
        value = values[row]

        # Prepare the SQL query
        sql_query = "INSERT INTO answers_submitted (question, answer) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql_query, (question_id, value))

    # Commit the changes to the database
    conn.commit()

    # Close the cursor and database connection
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return html.Div("Answers submitted successfully!")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```